# VS 17.3.0 Preview 2.0 Not paring with Mac - MAUI

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I am trying to develop a MAUI application for iOS & Android with Razor Class Library.
While trying to Pair my Mac with Visual Studio I face issue. In log I get below errors

*Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.IOSServerStateContextExtensions Error: 0 : An error occurred while trying to get the current Xcode location in the connected Mac
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.MacOsxVersionValidator Warning: 0 : An unexpected error occurred while trying to get environment information for the connected Mac*

When I try to connect without opening any .sln file, I could pair the Mac without any issue. With any project open, I face issue.

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please make sure that you have Xcode installed and then try to clear the XMA cache on the Mac. You can refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac

Comment: This worked for me and I could pair without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to clear the XMA cache on the Mac. You can refer to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac) for more details.